# How to disable or enable firebase push notification onMessageReceived?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

How to disable and enable FCM push notifications `onMessageReceived` by button click in android?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question ?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do, what you've tried and what results are you currently getting

Comment: I want to write that when I click on the button, the program does not receive any notifications from the FiberBase, and with one more click on it I enable it?

Comment: i tired do stop onmessagerecive programically

Answer (score 0):

You can manually register your GcmBroadcastReceiver at startup and unregister on exit.

It sounds like you want to control whether components published in your manifest are active, not dynamically register a receiver (via Context.registerReceiver()) while running.

If so, you can use PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting() to control whether these components are active:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName, int, int)

Note if you are only interested in receiving a broadcast while you are running, it is better to use registerReceiver(). A receiver component is primarily used for when you need to make sure your app is launched every time the broadcast is sent.